# query same value in a column in different in other tow

Tags: plsql

I have a table COND with:

```
ORDERNO    NAME    OUTPUT SIGN

12         HOUSE    O     +
13         CAR      O     -
14         BOOK     I     +
13         HOUSE    I     A
```

I need to get the name of the rows that have:
Same name and two rows:
one with OUTPUT = O and SIGN = +
another row with OUTPUT= I and SIGN = A.

In these example only should get:
HOUSE

Only Value HOUSE.
These value is the correct

Comment: you merged 4 records in one line and you expect people to understand a very awfully written question. Please make it more clear

Comment: Sorry I've edited the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT NAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN OUTPUT = 'O' and SIGN = '+' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN OUTPUT = 'I' and SIGN = 'A' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! Only a little question if I would like to one of the two conditions meet but the another not. I mean one row with output=O and sing '+' but shouldn't be the row with output='I' and sign ='A' .  How could I do these?

Comment: You should ask a new question in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be the `intersect` set operator:

For sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

   ORDERNO NAME  OUTPUT     SIGN
---------- ----- ---------- ----------
        12 HOUSE O          +
        13 CAR   O          -
        14 BOOK  I          +
        13 HOUSE I          A
```

Query, literally saying what you described:

```
SQL> select name from test where output = 'O' and sign = '+'
  2  intersect
  3  select name from test where output = 'I' and sign = 'A';

NAME
-----
HOUSE

SQL>
```

Yes, I know - it scans the same table twice, but is simple and easy to understand.